# TXR: How to combine all lines where the following line begins with a tab?

Tags: text-processing

I am trying to parse the text output of a shell command using txr.

The text output uses a tab indented line following it to continue the current line (not literal `\t` characters as I show below). Note that on other variable assignment lines (that don't represent extended length values), there are leading spaces in the input.

```
Variable Group: 1
 variable = the value of the variable
 long_variable = the value of the long variable
\tspans across multiple lines
 really_long_variable = this variable extends
\tacross more than two lines, but it
\tis unclear how many lines it will end up extending
\tacross ahead of time

Variable Group: 2
 variable = the value of the variable in group 2
 long_variable = this variable might not be that long
 really_long_variable = neither might this one!
```

How might I capture these using the txr pattern language? I know about the `@(freeform)` directive and it's optional numeric argument to treat the next `n` lines as one big line. Thus, it seems to me the right approach would be something like:

```
@(collect)
Variable Group: @i
 variable = @value
@(freeform 2)
 long_variable = @long_value
@(set long_value @(regsub #/[\t ]+/ "" long_value))
@(freeform (count-next-lines-starting-with-tab))
 really_long_variable = @really_long_value
@(set really_long_value @(regsub #/[\t ]+/ "" really_long_value))
@(end)
```

However, it's not clear to me how I might write the `count-next-lines-starting-with-tab` procedure with TXR lisp. On the other hand, maybe there is another better way I could approach this problem. Could you provide any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's apply the KISS principle; we don't need to bring in `@(freeform)`. Instead we can separately capture the main line and the continuation lines for the (potentially) multi-line variables. Then, intelligently combine them with `@(merge)`:

```
@(collect)
Variable Group: @i
 variable = @value
 long_variable = @l_head
@  (collect :gap 0 :vars (l_cont))
        @l_cont
@  (end)
 really_long_variable = @rl_head
@  (collect :gap 0 :vars (rl_cont))
        @rl_cont
@  (end)
@  (merge long_variable l_head l_cont)
@  (merge really_long_variable rl_head rl_cont)
@(end)
```

Note that the big indentations in the above are supposed to be literal tabs. Instead of literal tabs, we can encode tabs using `@\t`.

Test run on the real data with `\t` replaced by tabs:

```
$ txr -Bl new.txr data
(i "1" "2")
(value "the value of the variable" "the value of the variable in group 2")
(l_head "the value of the long variable" "this variable might not be that long")(l_cont ("spans across multiple lines") nil)
(rl_head "this variable extends" "neither might this one!")
(rl_cont ("across more than two lines, but it" "is unclear how many lines it will end up extending"
          "across ahead of time") nil)
(long_variable ("the value of the long variable" "spans across multiple lines")
 ("this variable might not be that long"))
(really_long_variable ("this variable extends" "across more than two lines, but it"
                       "is unclear how many lines it will end up extending" "across ahead of time")
 ("neither might this one!"))
```

We use a strict `collect` with `:vars` for the continuation lines, so that the variable is bound (to `nil`) even if nothing is collected. `:gap 0` prevents these inner collects from scanning across lines that don't start with tabs: another strictness measure.

`@(merge)` has "special" semantics for combining lists of strings that haver different nesting levels; it's perfect for assembling data from different levels of collection and is basically tailor made for this kind of thing. This problem is very similar to extracting HTTP, Usenet or e-mail headers, which can have continuation lines.

---

On the topic of how to write a Lisp function to look ahead in the data, the most important aspect is how to get a handle on the data at the current position. The TXR pattern matching works by backtracking over a lazy list of strings (lines/records).　We can use the `@(data)` directive to capture the list pointer at the given input position. Then we can just treat that as a list:

```
@(data here)
@(bind tab-start-lines @(length (take-while (f^ #/\t/) here))
```

Now `tab-start-lines` has a count of how many lines in the input start with tabs. However, `take-while` has a termination condition bug, unfortunately; if the following data consists of nothing but one or more `tab` lines, it misbehaves.⚠ Until TXR 166 is released, this requires a little workaround: `(take-while [iff stringp (f^ #/\t/)] here)`.

Comment: Thanks, I was curious where I might use the merge directive.